# How to make Mega Menu into a click instead of hover

Tags: javascript, css, megamenu

I tried search everywhere but I'm having troubles with the javascript to make my megamenu a click event rather than hover. The solutions on stackoverflow for this sort of thing only seems to be for a ul/li format. Whereas this MegaMenu is a ul/li and div format. So can you help me?

Here's the javascript:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function () {
$('.dropdown-menu').not(this).children('ul').slideUp("slow");
$(this).children('.mega-menu-inner').slideToggle("slow");
});

$('.dropdown-menu').blur(function () {
$('.dropdown-inside').hide('slow', function () {});
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kschell/ms74wnry/16/

Here's the link to the actual menu: http://drive-in-autosound.mybigcommerce.com/ 
I'm trying to make the links click instead of hover. I want the users to click on it to open it and to click on it again to close it. Also if the user click on "Car Audio" (dropdown expands) then clicks on "Window Tint" then the "Car Audio" dropdown would close.